# Rails 3 URL validation that excludes some patterns

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Is it possible to use `validates_exclusion_of` with regular expressions?

That would ensure that URLs matching these specific patterns can't be validated nor inserted into db.

What would be the best approach to code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways I might do it, depending on the circumstance.

First, if I am going to have to match some patterns and then exclude others I might do something like this:

```
validates_format_of :url, :with => /swanky pattern/, :unless => :beavis

def beavis
  self.url.match(/beavis/)
end
```

Or if you just need to exclude certain patterns

```
validate :i_hate_beavis

def i_hate_beavis
  errors.add(:url, 'cannot be beavis') if self.url.match(/beavis/)
end
```

resources: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validate

Comment: I chose your solution and adapted it. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

I took Geoff's approach and implemented the following:

```
validate :url_is_acceptable

URL_BLACKLIST = [
  /http:\/\/www.some-website.com\/.*/,
  /http:\/\/www.other-website.com\/.*/
]

def url_is_acceptable
  URL_BLACKLIST.each do |blacklisted_url|
    if self.url =~ blacklisted_url
      errors.add(:not_acceptable, "is not acceptable")
      return
    end
  end
end
```